# Refreshing Integer Value After Disabling Button

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm trying to complete a fairly basic login style page using Android Studio. If the user logs in incorrectly 3 times, the login button is disabled for a period of time, before being enabled again. I was wondering how to get the value 'counter' to reset to the original value of three again once the login button is re-enabled.

```
 /* switch statement which changes colour of background depending on value of counter*/
                switch (counter) {
                    case 2:
                        tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        b1.setEnabled(false);
                        check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        b1.setEnabled(false);

                        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b1.setEnabled(true);

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).start();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Even though I have provided the answer below. The question is more using local variables in anonymouse inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the value counter as member variable of a class and set it back to anything in the run method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any implementation which includes counter over here. Can you modify your question and show where and how are you defining and decreasing a counter?